# Laravel Image Default

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

My user uploads a profile picture which is stored in storage/profile_picture/user1.png. I use Filesystem and Storage classes to do so.

To retrieve the image I use `{!! Html::image(route('profile.thumbnail', $user->profilepic_filename), "Your Picture Here", ['class'=>'img-responsive']) !!}`

In my Controller I have

```
public function thumbnail($filename)
{
    $user = User::where('profilepicture_filename', '=', $filename)->firstOrFail();
    $file = Storage::disk('local_profile')->get($user->profilepicture_filename);


    //$file = URL::asset('/images/default_profilepicture.png'); //doesn't work

    return (new Response($file, 200))->header('Content-Type', $mime);

}
```

}

I want to get a default image if the profile picture is not found or not uploaded. How can I do so?

Thanks,

K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like this I would just override the accessor (aka getter) on your `User` model.

http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Any database column, such as `profilepicture_filename` can be manipulated after it's retrieved using a `get___Attribute` method, where ___ is the column name in Camel Case

```php
class User
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProfilepictureFilenameAttribute()
    {
        if (! $this->attributes['profilepicture_filename'])) {
            return '/images/default_profilepicture.png';
        }

        return $this->attributes['profilepicture_filename'];
    }
}
```

Now you simply have to do

```
<img src="{{ asset($user->profilepicture_filename) }}">
```

And it will display either their picture or the default if they don't have one. You no longer need the thumbnail route.

Answer (score 2):

you could just do in you view:

```
@if(!file_exist($file->name))
    <img src="/path/to/default.png">
@else 
    <img src="{{$file->name}}">
@endif
```

or in your controller:

```
    if(!$file)
    {
       $file = '.../default/blah.png'; 
    }
```